# Get SelectedItem's Id in dynamically generated Menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu

I have created a Menu Dynamically.

Here is the structure of my Table:

```
MenuItemId      int     PrimaryKey
MenuItemName    nvarchar(50)
ParentId        int
NavigateURL     nvarchar(500)
```

Here is the C# code to get that data in Heirarchical structure:

```
private void GetMenuItems()
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spGetMenuData", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        if (dr["ParentID"].ToString().Trim() == "")
        {
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
            item.Text = dr["MenuItemName"].ToString();
            item.NavigateUrl = dr["NavigateUrl"].ToString();

            foreach (DataRow drChild in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (drChild["ParentID"].ToString() == dr["MenuItemID"].ToString())
                {
                    GetChildItems(ds, drChild, item);
                }
            }

            Menu1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

}

private static void GetChildItems(DataSet ds, DataRow dr, MenuItem item)
{
    MenuItem childItem = new MenuItem();
    childItem.Text = dr["MenuItemName"].ToString();
    childItem.NavigateUrl = dr["NavigateUrl"].ToString();

    foreach (DataRow drChild in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        if (drChild["ParentID"].ToString() == dr["MenuItemID"].ToString())
        {
            GetChildItems(ds, drChild, childItem);
        }
    }

    item.ChildItems.Add(childItem);
}
```

Here is my Html:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="" BackColor="#B5C7DE" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana"
    Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284E98" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px"  BorderStyle="Groove" BorderColor="WhiteSmoke"  DynamicMenuStyle-BorderStyle="Outset">
    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="Red" ForeColor="White" />
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="15px" VerticalPadding="10px" />
    <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#99ff99" />
    <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="Green" />
    <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="Blue" ForeColor="White" />
    <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="10px" VerticalPadding="10px" />
    <StaticMenuStyle BackColor="#ff6699" />
    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="Green" />
</asp:Menu>
```

Now I want to get the selectedItem's MenuItemId from that menu.

Can anybody tell me how can I get the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

`string s = Menu1.SelectedValuePath=ID;`

Comment: Thanks for answering my first question. My Menu is located inside MasterPage. I want the value of SelectedMenuItem's Id in Content Page's HTML or Designer whatever you call. Can you please tell me how can I get that?

Comment: @ChavdaVineet You want to grab the selectedmenuitem's id using the html info? and not using ASP.NET properties?  I'm a little confused at what you're attempting to do.

Comment: @user3267755 Yes, ChavdaVineet is my friend. Both of us are struggling with the same problem. We don't want in HTML, but in some kind of markup language like HTML which is used in asp.net. I think its the ASP.NET properties. But can you post a working sample code, so that we can learn from that.

Comment: ASP.NET uses HTML in combination with ASP.NET controls which have the prefix <asp:> like your <asp:Menu>.  You can modify these controls with C# or VB.NET in the code-behind when a server event happens by using their assigned ID's.  You can also access their properties by using javascript or jQuery on the front-end.  There are many other possibilities, but I'm still unclear of which way you are trying to get the selectedmenuitems ID.

Comment: Now, we are clear. We want to have SelectedMenuItem's Id in HTML in Combination with ASP.NET. Basically, we have used a DataList on a Page. This dataList is bound to the Database using SqlDataSource. We want to supply the SelectedMenuItem's Id to a query supplied to SqlDataSource, so that we can get the data matching with the Id of the selectedMenuItem.